# Disabling or hiding title bar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mdi

I'm using the http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ library to handle MDI in my WPF application.

I've got a Canvas which contains a child container, which in turn contains a number of small windows.

I would like to disable the titlebar on my child windows.  Is this possible?  I haven't found a single property which achieves this, especially since the `MdiChild` object is of type `Control` rather than `Window`.

This is my code for creating an MDIChild, which contains an object of my `TableWindow` class.

```
            MdiChild child = new MdiChild()
            {
                MaximizeBox = false,
                MinimizeBox = false,
                Resizable = true,
                ShowIcon = false,
                Content = tableWindow.Content as UIElement
            };

            mainContainer.Children.Add(child);
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `WindowStyle` to `None`..??

Comment: Of course I have, there's no WindowStyle property since MdiChild is a Control rather than a Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a `Control` so you have to `override` its default template (`ControlTemplate`).

In source code you will see two xamls - `Aero.xaml` and `Luna.xaml` containing the style for MdiChild control. Source code can be seen [here](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/81799#666806). Just get rid of `StackPanel(ButtonsPanel)` containing buttons and `Grid(HeaderContent)`.

Thats the power WPF gives us, you can customize any control to give it a look whatever you feel like by overriding its `ControlTemplate`.

**EDIT**

To override the template you have to redefine it in your xaml. What you have to do is `create a style again in your Window resources, set the template for the control` and it will automatically override the default control template. Simply copy paste the entire template from [here](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/81799#666806) and remove the StackPanel and Grid which i mentioned above.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type mdi:MdiChild}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                  <!-- Copy paste entire template here and
                       just remove the StackPanel and Grid -->
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**EDIT2**

Replace your `ControlTemplate` with this to disable the title bar but still enable the drag operation and resizable operation for your control -

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mdi:MdiChild}">
   <Border Name="BaseBorder" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0"
           Background="{StaticResource BackBorderBackgroundBrush}"
           BorderBrush="{StaticResource BackBorderBrush}">
               <Grid>
                  <Border Name="ContentBorder"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                         <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                   </Border>
                  <Thumb Name="DragThumb" Height="20" Margin="0,0,40,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0"/>

                   <Rectangle Name="LeftBorder" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"
                              Fill="{StaticResource NearBorderBrush}" />
                   <Rectangle Name="TopBorder" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                              RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"
                              Fill="{StaticResource NearBorderBrush}" />
                   <Rectangle Name="RightBorder" Width="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                              RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"
                              Fill="{StaticResource FarBorderBrush}" />
                   <Rectangle Name="BottomBorder" Height="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                              RadiusX="9" RadiusY="9"
                              Fill="{StaticResource FarBorderBrush}" />

                   <Thumb Name="ResizeLeft" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Margin="0,6,0,6" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeTop" Height="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                          Margin="6,0,6,0" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeNS"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeRight" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          Margin="0,6,0,6" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeWE"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeBottom" Height="6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                          Margin="6,0,6,0" Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeNS"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeTopLeft" Width="6" Height="6" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" 
                          Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeTopRight" Width="6" Height="6" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeNESW"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeBottomRight" Width="6" Height="6" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                          Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeNWSE"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
                   <Thumb Name="ResizeBottomLeft" Width="6" Height="6" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                          Opacity="0" Cursor="SizeNESW"
                          IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding Resizable}" />
             </Grid>
       </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, this problem has been driving me crazy. I'll try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Could you kindly explain how I can override the ControlTemplate for this class?

Comment: Hi again - I tried doing this, however the problem is that the window now appears to have two title bars strangely enough - I posted a screenshot in my edit

Comment: Strange..!! Works for me though.

Comment: Have you Copy/paste the entire style from the link?

Comment: I think that's the problem actually - I'm getting many errors when doing that. From where till where should I copy paste?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18340/discussion-between-dot-net-and-rv1987)